# Проблемы с метками. Сбой при правке вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, метки

Два коротких связанных между собой вопроса. Я их объединил в одну тему.

1. Непонятный сбой. Вот в [этом вопросе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437791/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F) стояла метка **обособленное**, это новая метка, созданная участником ради этого вопроса. Я попытался внести правку: удалить метку **обособленное** и заменить её на стандартную метку **обособление**. В результате метка удалилась, но новая метка к вопросу не подвязалась. Я попытался использовать оба инструмента: "править метки" в вопросе и "править вопрос" — безуспешно.
2. Автор упомянутого выше вопроса — лидер по созданию новых меток (обычно "плохих"). За последнюю неделю это третья её метка, которая попалась мне на глаза. Ещё в одном её вопросе я заменил её новую метку "уп**арв**лени**я**" на стандартную метку "управление". Просьба к модераторам сделать замечание этому участнику.

Вопрос: что теперь делать с "пустыми" метками ("упарвления" и "обособленное")? Нужно ли их как-то удалять или сигнализировать здесь? Или лучше не обращать на них внимания? (Интересует не просто ответ в данном конкретном случае, но рекомендуемый порядок действий).

PS. Удалил (заменил) ещё одну метку в каком-то вопросе: "сказу**меы**е" и эта метка тоже стала пустой.

Comment: Прошу прощения за невнимательность и создание неудобств. Может, чтобы избавиться от "пустых" меток, можно удалить мои вопросы, к которым они привязаны, если другие участники согласны? Если можно просто удалить "пустые" метки, я это сделаю, только я не поняла, где они, если они уже либо исправлены, либо удалены редакторами моих вопросов? Я не разбираюсь в технических вопросах сайта, поэтому не могу предложить конкретных действий по управлению метками. Постараюсь внимательнее относится к меткам в следующих своих вопросах. Простите.

Comment: @Юлия Спасибо за понимание! _Постараюсь внимательнее относится к меткам в следующих своих вопросах._ Вот этого будет вполне достаточно; не нужно ничего больше делать, тем более удалять вопросы — у Вас хорошие вопросы и они имеют ценность для форума. Мне жаль, что пришлось сделать это замечание, но я считаю, что лучше один раз пройти неловкую ситуацию и объясниться. Свой комментарий в той теме я удалил, а этот форум совсем не такой публичный.

Comment: @Юлия теперь всё хорошо, ничего не нужно удалять — крайности ни к чему! Просто постарайтесь внимательнее относиться к подбору меток, а другие участники всегда помогут подкорректировать выбранные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Метка [обособление](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) является синонимом метки [пунктуация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f), каждый раз первая автоматически меняется на вторую. Это связано с тем, что [обособление](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) на данный момент меткой, самостоятельность которой обоснован; если вы считаете, что это неправильно, пожалуйста, создайте отдельную тему на Мете и опишите, почему важно ввести метку [обособление](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).
2. Я просмотрел последние вопросы упомянутого автора и не нашел существенных недостатков в применяемых им метках. Думаю, что теперь всё хорошо.

Пустые метки удаляются системой, но если вы наблюдаете частую путаницу между верным и ошибочным написаниями, то стоит [предложить синоним метки](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) или создать вопрос здесь, на Мете, с описанием проблемы.

Благодарю вас за помощь и искренне прошу прощения, что в последнее время не успеваю быстро отвечать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Срочности никакой нет, я здесь надолго :)  Понятно теперь, как работают синонимы. Привлечь Юлию к разговору я зря поспешил, ну да что ж теперь.